# A possible Donnie Darko reference to 2002

Tags: reference, donnie-darko

*[Donnie Darko](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donnie_Darko)* the film features a recurring scene consisting of fast-cut composition of various overlaying elements atop a large pupil. One of these elements appears to be a stack trace/core dump for some kernel.

Upon taking a closer look (by pausing the movie) I discovered the following frame:

[image: Image: Donnie Dark Movie Frame]

The image doesn't show very clearly but the most important text is copied below:

```
Kernel version:
Latwin Kernel Version 6.1:
Fri Sep 6 23:09:31 PDT 2002; root:xnu/xnu-344.2.obj-1/RELEASE_PPC
```

Aside from the obscure "Latwin" kernel which I can't find any info on (looks like an Apple based system though), the date **Fri Sep 6 23:09:31 PDT 2002** is of higher relevance here.

To my knowledge the movie was produced in 2001 and the frame itself was taken from a director's cut <strike>(which should be even older than the final cut?)</strike>. **Edit:** Turns out the director's cut was released in 2004. But it does seem strange to have added scenes post-final cut that were produced between the actual release (2001) and the director's cut (2004). Does the kernel dump appear in the original theatrical release?

Is the year 2002 here meant to be some reference to the future? Though, in contrast to the 1988 setting, it does seem quite irrelevant. Or am I over-thinking it and the computer that produced that kernel dump just had a date/time setting off by 1 year?

P.S: Information on the particular "Latwin" kernel would be nice too.

Comment: The [director's cut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donnie_Darko#Director.27s_cut) came out in 2004, if you're curious.

Comment: @Catija Does that mean the kernel dump is an added scene in 2002? Seems strange to call it a director's cut but have scenes added (especially at some intermediate time like 2002). Also, do you know if the original release featured the kernel dumps?

Comment: No clue, just saying that your assertion that the director's cut was done first is wrong. I haven't actually seen the film... love the music, though.

Comment: "But it does seem strange to have added scenes post-final cut..." - unless you're George Lucas, then it's par for the course HA HA.

Comment: @Catija Oh well, that wasn't something I expected but I guess it seems logical. I'll be getting my hands on the original theatrical release to see if the kernel dump is present in the meantime.

Comment: Sounds like a great idea! If you find anything out, feel free to come and answer the question! We may have others here that have some insight, too. It's an interesting question... though probably more so to people who've seen it.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1812/49).

Comment: Redoing (or occasionally even adding) computer-based effects sequences for a "director's cut" is actually pretty standard, I think. Take a look at the differences between the background images during the final confrontation in Blade Runner among the different cuts.

Comment: FYI, there are similar kernel dumps on Z Nation, with Sepwin and Latwin instead of Darwin IIRC.

Comment: And, apparently, also used in "The girl with the dragon tatoo": https://twitter.com/jollyjinx/status/14310591025

Comment: You have the same console output in the "World's Most Wanted" series on Netflix. Specifically at 37:10, Episode 1. https://www.netflix.com/title/81013210

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK, here's what I could find out:

I'm going to say that this is specific to the Director's cut of the film.

Here's why...

[This site](http://www.movie-censorship.com/report.php?ID=1796) goes second by second describing the changes between the original and Director's cut (DC).

Search for "8:53 min. - 9:21 min."

Here they introduce that the eye is completely added to the DC:

> After the dawn of the new day (2.10.1988) via text insert the DC features a long sequence of blackscreen with threatening sound-effects, until eventually Frank's ghost-voice announces: "Wake up!" **After that, we see a closeup of an eye with an expanding pupil. Then, for a millisecond, Franks rabbit-head is cut in (like in Fight Club). The transition shot of the Darkos' house is much longer in the DC, too.**
>
> From now on, the eye always symbolizes the tasks and abilities which he gets "implanted" by Frank.

Now, search for : "113:38 min. - 113:45 min."

This shows a nearly identical image to your screen capture and states that there are 7 extra seconds:

> The eye again. This time accompanied by a countdown from the off.

So, now we know that the eye was completely added to the director's cut of the film...

#### Does the content **mean** anything?

So, what does the content mean, if anything?

Well, turns out it doesn't really mean anything... Here's the [actual content](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1523161) of a similar error with the same Kernel identifier:

> `Kernel version:`
>
> `Darwin Kernel Version 6.1:`
>
> `Fri Sep 6 23:09:31 PDT 2002; root:xnu/xnu-344.2.obj~1/RELEASE_PPC`

The 2002 date refers to the build date that that particular version of the kernel was built, which is identical to the build date mentioned in the linked Apple forum discussion.

It seems that someone found this Mac OS 10.3.x error text and decided to use it for the graphics. They did make the (probably smart) choice to change "Darwin" to "Latwin" to avoid clashing with Apple's litigation team. So the content and date mentioned have nothing to do with the film (assuming the director didn't *actually* create time travel).

This was also discussed briefly on this Reddit [thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/osx/comments/24mpsx/mac_os_x_crash_logs_are_used_as_decorations_in/).

Comment: Yep, this seems to be correct. I've compared the DC to the theatrical release and found the original to completely lack any of these "eye scenes", confirming that the date likely doesn't have any relevance. A big headslap for me for not realizing that Latwin was likely made up (I've literally seen identical Darwin dumps but assumed Latwin was some older, different version). And finally, kudos to you for being able to find all this information (especially that reddit thread) **without even watching the movie** (though you really should, it's highly recommended).

Comment: @CPUTerminator My husband gets the credit. He's a programmer and I've enlisted his help on this one... He's also seen the film and hadn't realized that I haven't. :D

Comment: Just one really tiny pedantic thing though, when you say "here is the actual error" the error there isn't exactly the same as the one in the movie (tell-tale is the different CPU that raised the error, `CPU 0` in the movie and `CPU 1` in the linked article). This is more of a FYI, and I'm not suggesting you do anything about it.

Comment: @CPUTerminator Sorry! I can't actually read the rest of the text other than what you transcribed because it's so tiny! :D

Comment: It's a pity they didn't change the date as well, since the movie is supposed to occur in the 80s.

Comment: If they were trying to rename Darwin to Latwin to avoid Apple's litigation team (note that Darwin was and is open source and Darwin isn't trademarked by Apple) then why didn't they remove apple in the com.apple.filesystems.afpfs line near the top of the picture?

Comment: @Yetoo to evoke the idea of an alternate reality?